# pow.cx not working due to .envrc file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-pow

I am trying to run the [pow server](http://pow.cx) but it stops when it sees the .envrc file in the root of my ruby on rails application. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/basecamp/pow/issues/462), which will occur for many rails users as the `spring gem` advises the use of a .envrc file that in used by `direnv`.  The solution as described [here](https://github.com/basecamp/pow/issues/73) is to wrap the contents of the .envrc file as follows:

```
if [ "$(type -t direnv_load)" = 'function' ]; then
  # Whatever you want only direnv to execute
fi
```

Incidentally, you may need to change your `config/development.rb` file so that

`config.asset_host = 'myapp.dev`

and then need to restart the application by

```
touch tmp/restart.txt
```